# Envolver tags similares

Tags: php, html

[1] Este é um exemplo do que gostaria de fazer, porém, não sei como aplicar ao meu caso.
Gostaria de envolver os itens do mesmo tipo em uma `ol` dele.

Texto original:

```
<li>
  <p>a) texto longo;</p>
</li>
<li>
  <p>b)  texto longo;</p>
</li>
<li>
  <p>I - texto longo;</p>
</li>
<li>
  <p>a) texto longo;</p>
</li>
<li>
  <p>b) texto longo;</p>
</li>
<li>
  <p>c)  texto longo;</p>
</li>
```

Gostaria que retornasse este valor:

```
<ol>
   <li>
     <p>a) texto longo;</p>
   </li>
   <li>
     <p>b)  texto longo;</p>
   </li>
</ol>
<li>
  <p>b)  texto longo;</p>
</li>
<ol>
   <li>
     <p>a) texto longo;</p>
   </li>
   <li>
     <p>b)  texto longo;</p>
   </li>
   <li>
     <p>c)  texto longo;</p>
   </li>
</ol>
```

[1] = http://board.phpbuilder.com/showthread.php?10368819-Turning-a-array-into-HTML-nested-list

Comment: Não esta claro o que você quer. Além do mais, repare que o HTML resultante exibido na sua pergunta é inválido.

Comment: Eu sei que o ol deve ficar dentro do li para aninhar ols, mas procurei resumir para não ficar longo.

Comment: Tenho uma lista que tem itens que começam com números romanos e outros que começam com a), b), c) e assim por diante, gostaria de envolver os itens do mesmo tipo em uma ol dele

Comment: Editei sua pergunta incluindo o comentário acima (e alguns outros detalhes), mas mesmo assim não parece ter ficado muito claro o que vc quer.  No primeiro exemplo está `a)`, `b)`, **`I)`**, `a)`, `b)`, `c)`, enquanto no segundo está (o resultado que vc quer) `a)`, `b)`, **`b)`**, `a)`, `b)`, `c)`. A saída correta não seria `a)`, `b)`, `a)`, `b)`, `c)` (apenas excluindo o `I)`?

Comment: Tem um li sobrando ali `</ol>
<li>
  <p>b)  texto longo;</p>
</li>
<ol>`

Comment: Esse li é do item "I"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso pode ser feito separando as tags `<li>` em um array com duas dimensões e depois uni-las adicionando a tag `<ol>` quando necessário.

Para separa-las pode-se usar a função `preg_match_all`, passando primeiro o regex, segundo o texto com as tags e terceiro uma variável vazia para retornar o que foi encontrado.

```
preg_match_all('/<li>\s*.*\s*<\/li>/', $documento, $matches);
```

O resultado é um array cujo primeiro item é um outro array com a lista de textos que combinam com o regex, os demais itens seriam os textos que combinam com os grupos do regex, porém neste regex não há grupos.

Para identificar o grupo basta pegar a primeira letra usando a função `preg_replace`, e verificar se é o inicio do grupo de letras ou romanos, alterando qual o tipo em uso, e incrementando o contador de grupos quando inicia um tipo diferente.

```
$tipo = '';
$ultimo = '';
$count = 0;
$grupos = array();
foreach ($matches[0] as $k => $li) {
    $letra = preg_replace('/\s*<li>\s*<p>\s*([a-zA-Z]).*<\/p>\s*<\/li>\s*/', '$1', $li);
    switch ($letra) {
    case 'a':
        $tipo = 'letra';
        break;
    case 'I':
        $tipo = 'romano';
        break;
    }
    if ($k == 0) {
        $grupos[$count][] = $li;
        $ultimo = $tipo;
    } else {
        if ($tipo != $ultimo) {
            $ultimo = $tipo;
            $count++;
        }
        $grupos[$count][] = $li;
    }
}
```

Por último basta adicionar a tag `<ol>` quando há mais de um item no grupo.

```
$html = '';
foreach ($grupos as $grupo) {
    if (count($grupo) > 1) {
        $html .= "<ol>\n".implode('', $grupo)."</ol>\n";
    } else {
        $html .= $grupo[0];
    }
}
echo $html;
```

Ao final temos o conteúdo esperado na variável `$html`